# How can I draw multiple vertex array on a single draw call in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es

I want to simulate a bunch of balls' movement. These balls are rendered as 12 vertices with GL_TRIANGLE_FAN. In my design, every ball object maintains an array of its own vertices attributes. However, every time I invoke `glDrawElements`, it only draws one `Vertex Buffer Object`. 1000 balls need 1000 draw call. It's not efficient. If I draw points instead of triangle fan, I could draw it as follow:

```
class Ball
{
public:
    GLfloat x, y;
    // ...
}

Ball balls[] = {Ball(100, 100), Ball(80, 120), ...};

void display()
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Ball), 0); // stride

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertex_num);
    //...
}
```

With `stride` parameter, I could 'choose' x, y from balls array and skip other members. I wonder how could I do the same thing when every object maintain an array of vertex attributes? Or I should extract all vertex attributes and combine them into a single VBO? But it needs extra code to maintain it and increases the coupling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all the objects are (exactly or mostly) the same, you should look into "*instanced*" rendering or drawing (i.e. [`glDrawArraysInstanced`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glDrawArraysInstanced), etc.)

If your objects are mostly different and mostly dynamic but have the same render state (textures, shaders, etc.,) and you can use OpenGL 4+, you should use "multi-draw indirect" facilities (i.e. [`glMultiDrawArraysIndirect`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glMultiDrawArraysIndirect), etc.) Note that the version requirement is a little tricky, when considering all the prior extensions, etc.

If your objects are not the same but are static, you should combine them into one (or a few) objects and draw those. This will need more code and will result in less flexibility, and you have to figure out whether it's worth the performance benefits or not.

If none of the above fits (i.e. your objects are all different, very dynamic, and you can't use modern OpenGL,) then you don't have any easy ways to improve your drawing efficiency. You'll probably need to employ ubershaders (actually, very few shaders that do *everything*), texture arrays (or bindless texturing) and other tricks.